# Multi-tenant Next.js + Tailwind App: How to change theme on the fly?

Tags: typescript, next.js, multi-tenant

I'm currently working on a multi-tenant Next.js + Tailwind application, where a tenant should be able to change the style/theme on the fly.

I can't seem to figure this challenge out, in my mind, one would need to rebuild the next.js application each time a style is changed but is it possible to somehow change a style for one tenant without rebuilding the application?

What I'm trying to achieve: The tenant updates a style parameter, which updates a database. When the tenants web app is reloaded, the new style is applied straight away without any delay and rebuild.

Comment: Is this a react application?

Comment: @ETCasual Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Use React's `Context` to render styles, ie. light / dark mode

Or.

Use a state management library / browser's localStorage to set styles and change the class of the html components in Tailwind

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working using a combination of looking at URLs, and sending server props to the client.

For example, i have my backend send some styles such as `primaryColor`.

Working example below:

1. In your page.tsx before the rendering code. You get the tenantId from the URL. Then you use that Id to retrieve the styles from the backend.

```
async function getSearchParams() {
  const headersInstance = headers();
  const pathname = headersInstance.get("referer");
  if (!pathname) return new URLSearchParams();

  const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(pathname.split("?")[1]);
  return urlSearchParams;
}

async function getStyles(tenantId: string) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/themes/${tenantId}`);
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    return {};
  }
}
```

2. Call these data in your server component & send them to your client component

```
export default async function Main({searchParams){
  const tenantId = searchParams?.tenantId || "";
  const styles = await getStyles(tenantId);

  return (
    <div>
      <ClientComponent styles={styles} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

3. In your client component, dynamically set the global css variables

```
const ClientComponent = ({styles}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--primary-color", primaryColor);
  }, [primaryColor]);

return (
<div className="bg-primary w-100 h-100">
my colour is changed
</div>
```